# google apps script mssql 2008 jdbc connection failed 2019

Tags: google-apps-script

My google apps script ran very well for last 2 years with MS SQL 2008R2.

However since yesterday I have been getting below error

```
"can't establish connection with database, please connection string".
```

I did a restart on every machine and tried connecting from other place. 
I can connect to my sql server without any problem.
I was wondering if anyone faced the same situation?

I guess google's JDBC version changed and can't support MSSQL2008???
Has anyone faced the same issue?

Comment: Check the Sunset Schedule [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/sunset)

Comment: @Cooper Did you mean to say "_this IS_ a sunset issue, it's listed on this link", or "_maybe_ this is a sunset issue, its listed on this link"? Only saying because I couldn't see a Jan 2019 reference on that page.

Comment: It looks not like sunset schedule.